# Object array method dispatching

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

In MATLAB's new object model (`classdef`, etc):  If I have an array of the object, and I call an ordinary method, is the methods called for each object, or for the entire array, i.e. is a single object passed into the method, or the entire array?  I know that in the old model, it got dispatched as the entire array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have:

```
classdef MyObject

methods
    function foo(obj)
    ...
end
```

And you then call

```
>> foo(myObjArray)
```

Then the single call to foo() will receive the entire array.  From there you can write code to handle a scalar case of obj or vector case of obj.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on if your method is vectorized.  For a trivial example:

### Not vectorized

```
function result = mySimpleMultiply(a,b)

result = a*b;
```

### Vectorized

```
function result = myVectorizedMultiply(a,b)

result = a.*b;
```

Comment: I sure you were trying to help, but how does this answer the question at all?

Comment: Maybe I should have added that MATLAB treats all variables like arrays, so if you have a single element, say x = 2, x is a 1-by-1 double array.  You then have to write your functions, OO or not, accordingly.